# Illegal constant pool index error in grails

Tags: grails, bytecode-manipulation

I have a grails application that i have deployed on my linode box. It was running fine for a few days but now gives this error on all pages:

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/InvokerInvocationException, method: getMessage signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;) Illegal constant pool index
```

Googling indicates that this is a weaving problem, but not how to solve. Has anyone encountered something similar?

Comment: Your site loads correctly for me

Comment: because i just restarted tomcat. i should remove the link as not to confuse people while i work on it

Comment: Are you running a sun JVM or OpenJDK?

Comment: java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 2):

I've just worked around this error in gwt... I don't have time to try all the possible values for the variables involved but it appears it was related to using different version of javac for different parts of the process... I was compiling the gwt code using jdk5 and running app code in jre6